# AWS buffer logs in CloudWatch before streaming to lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logging, aws-lambda, architecture

Is there a way to buffer X log messages from a CloudWatch log group and only then stream it to a lambda function? I'll elaborate:

I have an app that I registered it's *CloudWatch* logs to stream to a *lambda* function which formats the logs and pushes them to *Elastic Search*.

So the flow is the following:
(app logs) -> (CloudWatch) -->(Lambda)-->(Elastic Search)

My problem is that my lambda function is invoked very often (most of the time single log message) and bombards ES with write requests, I would like to write the logs in bulks, i.e wait until 30 new logs and then invoke the lambda for the 30 logs bulk.

The only way I found to achieve this is to use Kinesis and Firehose but those services cost extra and I want to avoid this.

Are there any other alternatives to achieve this without using something like LogStash?
I am assuming this is a very common usage so there must be some easy way to solve this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I would investigate [Functionbeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/functionbeat/current/functionbeat-overview.html) whose main goal is to stream Cloudwatch logs (among others) to ES. Extremely easy to deploy and operate, no fiddling with Lambda code, etc. A MUST if you're evolving in the AWS environment yet still want to leverage ES as a log engine

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering what you ended up doing in the situation. I believe if you use functionbeats you can not use aws ES you have to create it manually.